# what is the value of all 32 bits set to 1 in int?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitvector

I was experimenting with bit operations in java

I tried setting bit index by index and this is what I have got.
Started setting with 0 th bit in the integer 0  to  31st bit (as int has got 32 bits max)

```
value  of0bits set: 1
value  of1bits set: 3
value  of2bits set: 7
value  of3bits set: 15
value  of4bits set: 31
value  of5bits set: 63
value  of6bits set: 127
value  of7bits set: 255
value  of8bits set: 511
value  of9bits set: 1023
value  of10bits set: 2047
value  of11bits set: 4095
value  of12bits set: 8191
value  of13bits set: 16383
value  of14bits set: 32767
value  of15bits set: 65535
value  of16bits set: 131071
value  of17bits set: 262143
value  of18bits set: 524287
value  of19bits set: 1048575
value  of20bits set: 2097151
value  of21bits set: 4194303
value  of22bits set: 8388607
value  of23bits set: 16777215
value  of24bits set: 33554431
value  of25bits set: 67108863
value  of26bits set: 134217727
value  of27bits set: 268435455
value  of28bits set: 536870911
value  of29bits set: 1073741823
value  of30bits set: 2147483647
value  of31bits set: -1
```

Ok great! Value of an int with bits from 
0 to 31st index (least to most significant bit)
are all set and the result is -1 - from the above  result

Let me try the other way:

```
System.out.println(BitVector.countSetBits( -1 ) )  \\ prints '0'
```

**Then, what is the value of all 32 bits set to 1  in int ?**

Added countSetBits function :

```
   static int countSetBits(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            count += n & 1;
            n >>= 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: As your output tells you, its `-1`.

Comment: But why is the count bits  function returning the number of bits set as 0 ?

Comment: What is this `BitVector`?

Comment: Your counter is off by one, btw.

Comment: Whatever `BitVector` is, its implementation of `countSetBits` is most likely wrong.

Comment: @Lothar or it's not being passed the correct value.

Comment: Added code  if countSetBits

Comment: Yup, this is wrong for half of all integers: `while (n > 0)`

Comment: `while (n > 0)`. I guess you see it yourself, why it returns 0 for `-1`

Comment: oops. thanks let me fix it and try

Comment: @AndyTurner `BitVector.countSetBits( -1 )`  doesn't look like that a wrong value is passed.

Comment: @AthulMuralidharan why might `while (n > 0)` not work if you pass in -1? Edited fixes to your code into my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch all the bits "on" using the `~` operator:

```
System.out.println(~0);
System.out.println("Number of bits set to 1: " + Integer.bitCount(~0));
```

prints:

```
-1
Number of bits set to 1: 32
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wbUeMQ)

---

Your `countSetBits` doesn't work for 2 reasons:

1. `while (n > 0)` won't loop with negative `n`. Change it to `n != 0`.
2. `n >>= 1` is signed shifting: this preserves the sign bit as you shift. Change it to `n >>>= 1`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sktjcT)

Comment: System.out.println(  "value : " + BitVector.countSetBits( ~0) ) ;
prints '0'

Answer (score 1):

The value is, as described here at [MSDN - UInt32.MaxValue Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The value of this constant is 4,294,967,295;
>   that is, hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFF.

You have been using an `Int32`(which is signed). Hence you got a `-1` at the last factor.

So if all bits are set to `1` the `integer` value `0xFFFFFFFF`will be

- `-1` for signed 32-bit `integer`
- `4,294,967,295` for unsigned 32-bit `integer`

Comment: What will be the value in a signed int ? When I call  the function to count bits in -1, it returns 0 )i.e zero bits are set.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, -1 is the correct interpretation of this 32-bit signed integer. This is because this is in two's-complement notation, in which the bit-patterns 0 to 2^31-1 (inclusive) are positive, and bit-patterns 2^31 to 2^32-1 (inclusive) are treated as negative. These negative numbers are actually the given number plus 2^32. Thus a number with all 32 bits set to 1 is equivalent to -1.